# How to programmatically set Focus with IP WebCam

Tags: vb.net, emgucv

I'm trying to capture images/snap shot from IP Cam/WebCam using the EMGU. I've tried the following code without success...

```
Imports Emgu
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure

Public Class Form1
    Dim camera As VideoCapture
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
        camera = New VideoCapture("https://192.168.244/photo.jpg")
        Dim img As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = camera.QueryFrame
        PictureBox1.Image = img.ToBitmap()
    End Sub
 End Class
```

How can I capture images from IP Cam and programmatically adjust the focus?

Comment: sorry, I was trying to ask how to capture images from IP Cam and before capturing every image it will programmatically focus.

Comment: Have you looked through the [beginner tutorials](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=608) and also the [Emgu site](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Hello_World_in_VB.NET)?

Comment: Thanks for replying....the beginners example was load images from file, but i need to download or capture images from IP Cam. I cant fins a clue to get the code that i want.

Comment: Hi Sir Paul, I tried the link beginner turtorials thay you gave, It will prompt an error, It says "The type initializer for Emgu.CV.CvInvoke. threw an exception"

Comment: I used the EMGU version 3, all the I have search to fix my problem it did not work me, in this version the dll for EMGU is Emgu.CV.UI.dll, Emgu.CV.UI.GL.dll and Emgu.CV.world.Dll and Open CV in x86 was only concrt140.dll,  cvextern.dll, msvcp140.dll, opencv_ffmpeg320.dll and vcruntime140.dll

Comment: does anybody encountered this error on this version (EMGU 3.2), i have search some fixes but all of it are for the older versions of EMGu. I have also tried the examples that comes when you download EMGU dlls, still have the same error....pls help.....need to access the IP cam

Answer (score 0):

Now I figure it out....i replaced the picturebox with imagebox controls from the EMGU.UI.DLL. And Im able to capture or snap shot of the video. I change the version of EMGU from version 3.2.0.2682.exe (44.5 MB) to 3.1.0.2282 (71.0 MB).
Here's my code...viola:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.UI
Imports Emgu.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports Emgu.CV.CvEnum


Public Class Form1
   Dim ImageCapture As Capture = New          
                           Emgu.CV.Capture("http://192.168.1.3:8080/video")

   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
                                                             Timer1.Tick
       Try

          ImageBox1.Image = ImageCapture.QueryFrame.ToImage(Of Bgr, Byte)()

          'PictureBox1.Image = imageViwer.ToBitmap

      Catch ex As Exception
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
      End Try

   End Sub

    Private Sub cmdCaptureImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                                               Handles cmdCaptureImage.Click
        ImageBox2.Image = ImageBox1.Image
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: May there's a bug in the version 3.2.0.2682, even I tried the default webcam got the same error "The type initializer for Emgu.CV.CvInvoke. threw an exception". But when try to use the older version 3.1.0.2282 it works well and got what I want.

Comment: for the code above is use for the IP WebCam software which installed in my android phone....so i use phone as my IP Cam